# In combination with when and run_once in ansible, it will accidentally skip the task

Tags: ansible

My inventory_hosts is as follows:

```
# inventory
[kafka]
192.168.1.1 
192.168.1.2 

[mysql]
192.168.1.3
```

My ansible-playbook  as follows:

site.yml:

```
- name: test
  hosts: all
  roles:
   - kafka
```

kafka roles tasks:

```
# main.yml
- include: test.yml
  when:  "'kafka' in group_names"




# test.yml
---
- name: get kafka groups length
  shell: echo "{{ groups['kafka']|length }}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Get the main control machine ip
  shell: ip addr show `ip route |awk '$2=="via" {print $5}' |head -1` | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}'| head -1 | cut -d '/' -f 1
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

`get kafka groups length` and `Get the main control machine ip` can be executed and delegated to local execution respectively

ACTUAL RESULTS

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.1]
ok: [192.168.1.2]
ok: [192.168.1.3]
META: ran handlers

TASK [kafka : get kafka groups length] ***************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.1.3] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False

TASK [kafka : Get the main control machine ip] ************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.1.3] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False
```

It’s not over yet. The trick to teasing people is that when I commented on this set of ips `mysql`, I found that the task could be executed.

```
 # inventory
 [kafka]
 192.168.1.1 
 192.168.1.2 

 #[mysql]
 #192.168.1.3
```

New run result(Is the result I want)：

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.1]
ok: [192.168.1.2]

TASK [kafka : get kafka groups length] ************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1 -> localhost]

TASK [kafka : Get the main control machine ip] ******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.1 -> localhost]
```

Why is this so how can we avoid this uncertain problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: "Why is this so how can we avoid this uncertain problem?"

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include: test.yml
      when: "'kafka' in group_names"

TASK ...
    skip_reason: Conditional result was False
```

A: Use [include_tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_tasks_module.html#include-tasks-dynamically-include-a-task-list). The inheritance should work as expected.

```
    - include_tasks: test.yml
      when: "'kafka' in group_names"
```

(tested with ansible 2.7.9)

---

**Details**

Quoting from [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

> **group_names**: List of groups the current host is part of

With the inventory

```
 [kafka]
 192.168.1.1
 192.168.1.2
```

the variable of all hosts is `group_names: [ "kafka" ]` and the play works as expected.

With the inventory

```
 [kafka]
 192.168.1.1
 192.168.1.2

 [mysql]
 192.168.1.3
```

the variable of one host is `group_names: [ "mysql" ]`. From what you've found out it seems that in [include](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html#include-include-a-play-or-task-list) *run_once* will be skipped if the condition of any host fails.

```
skipping: [192.168.1.3] => changed=false 
  skip_reason: Conditional result was False
```

Comment: Now there is no use of the `include` task, it will be skipped, please help me to see it again, because this post is too long, so another post was posted            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57470872/ansibles-when-condition-combined-with-run-once-will-accidentally-skip-some-task

Comment: What about include_tasks? This solves the problem. Right?