# Ansible's when condition combined with run_once will accidentally skip some tasks that should not be skipped

Tags: ansible

My inventory_hosts is as follows:

```
# inventory
[kafka]
192.168.1.1 
192.168.1.2 

[mysql]
192.168.1.3
```

My ansible-playbook as follows:

site.yml:

```
- name: test
  hosts: all
  roles:
   - kafka
```

kafka roles tasks:

```
# main.yml
- name: get kafka groups length
  shell: echo "{{ groups['kafka']|length }}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: "'kafka' in group_names"
```

EXPECTED RESULTS

`get kafka groups length` can be executed and delegated to local execution respectively and only once

ACTUAL RESULTS

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [192.168.1.1]
ok: [192.168.1.2]
ok: [192.168.1.3]

TASK [kafka : get mongodb groups length] ************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [192.168.1.3]
```

Very strange design, I think it should not be skipped, but he did skip it, what should I do? I expect the same result

Comment: Why is it necessary to run it in the role? Have you tested it without the role? Is this different?

Answer (score 1):

From the Ansible documentation:

> `group_names` is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in

You are only running your task once, so it only runs on the first host, and that host only belongs to the `kafka` group. This means that your `group_names` variable on that run only includes `kafka`.

Try this instead:

```
- name: get kafka groups length
  shell: echo "{{ groups['kafka']|length }}"
  run_once: true
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: groups['kafka'] is defined
```